# jQuery - If "two blank spaces is inserted" do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, autocomplete

I'm looking for a code that when user type two consecutive blank spaces, the autocomplete is turned off. Now, if the "#" isn't present, the autocomplete is turned off too.

**This is my code:**

```
// "post-input" is text-area element
var input = $("#post-input");

if (input.val().search("#") === -1 ){
     var blankResult = [];
     input.autocomplete({
         source: blankResult 
     });
     input.attr('autocomplete','off');
}
```

As you can see, this works, but now I want add the second "feature": if user type two blank spaces (consecutive), the autocomplete will be disabled. I can do something like `input.val().search("#") === -1 || input.val().search(" ") === 2`?

Note: I know that the upper code will never be true, but I mean do something like this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match two spaces using regexp `/  /g`

```
if (input.val().search("#") === -1 || (/  /g.test(input.val()))) {
    //code here
}
```

Read [RegExp test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

For matching last two characters

```
var last2 = input.val().slice(-2); //gets last two characters of string
if (input.val().search("#") === -1 || (/  /g.test(last2))) {
    //code here
}
```

or

```
var last2 = input.val().slice(-2); //gets last two characters of string
if (input.val().search("#") === -1 || last2 = '  ') {
    //code here
}
```

Read [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Thanks, I will test. But what `.test(input.val())` do?

Comment: And I think this matches any two blank spaces in the textarea, not just the last ones, or I'm wrong? I want check if the last two input's in the textarea was blank spaces.

Comment: Now understand the use of .test :P

Comment: @FernandoPaladini do you want to check for last two values separated by spaces ??

Comment: The user was typing, if he type one space nothings happen. If he type the second space (consecutive of the first space), Autocomplete is disabled. Don't care if already have a two blank spaces in text area, what will be counted is the two last inputs.

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful provisionally